# What is the SQL statement to give a user group the ability to pass on privileges to another user?

Tags: oracle, sql-grant

I am trying to grant privileges in Oracle for a new user group to be able to 1. read, 2. update and 3. add records.

I think I have the SQL statement for that settled (see below) but I then want to make it so that this new user can in turn pass these privileges on to other users as well?

So far I have:

GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
ON Example_Table
TO New_User_Group;

Please help!

Comment: @Andrew Sayer has shown you _how_.  But I'd strongly caution you against it.  It is a huge security risk.  If you want others to have those privs, then grant the same role (NEW_USER_GROUP) to them.  BTW, there is no concept of "user group" in oracle.

Comment: thanks @EdStevens - i am a student so it is theoretical at the moment but i really appreciate the advice.

Comment: I have a somewhat different view on this than Ed Stevens. Granting "with grant option" is a huge security risk if it is done mindlessly. It is OK if it is used as intended. Which is true of any tool in any industry, really. The big security risk arises when this tool is used as a shortcut for something else; but there are cases when you may need more granular access to "granting" than by just granting roles left and right.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `with grant option` clause
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/GRANT.html#GUID-20B4E2C0-A7F8-4BC8-A5E8-BE61BDC41AC3